# set LD_LIBRARY_PATH on VPS red-hat linux

Tags: linux, apache, redhat, vps

Where and how should I set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`?

I tried to add following code to `.bash_profile`:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib/folder_with_library/
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

I restart apache but in `phpinfo()` i still see errors, so libraries hasn't been loaded.

Any help how to set this path?

I need to set that on VPS server - os is linux red-hat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTPd doesn't use user files. You must modify the `httpd` initscript (under `/etc/init.d`) to export the variable before starting the server.

But best is to figure out where the library in question actually belongs and put it there.

Comment: I add `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib/folder_with_library/` to `/etc/init.d/httpd` and restart it but in `phpinfo()` I cant see apache load libraries I need.